# Adding thickness to minecraft second layer without z-fighting

Tags: extrude, clipping, z-fighting

I was trying to add some thickness to the second layer of a minecraft skin like this.

[image]

I tried extruding faces, but it created a lot a z-fighting, how do i give thickness to the second layer without z-fighting?

[image]